# Specialization of radical ideals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $I\subseteq \mathbb C[x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_m]$ be a prime ideal. Consider the variety $V:=V(I)$ in $\mathbb C^n\times \mathbb C^m$ it defines (it is irreducible.) Let $\pi$ be the projection of $V$ onto the second factor $\mathbb C^m$. For generic $y'\in \pi(V)$ is it true that the specialization $I(y')$ is radical?, where
\begin{align}
I(y'):=\{f(x,y'):f\in I\}\subseteq \mathbb C[x_1,\ldots,x_n].
\end{align}

Observe that this is not true for all $y\in \pi(V)$. Take for instance the radical ideal generated by the single polynomial $x^2+y$. Then the specialization $y=0$ yields the ideal generated by $x^2$ which is not radical.

Any help or reference is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this reference will help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168979/when-a-scheme-theoretical-fiber-is-reduced.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not so familiar with scheme language. Do you know if that reference is saying what I'm asking?

Comment: Yes, the spectrum of $\mathbb C[x_1, \ldots, x_n]/I(y')$ is isomorphic to the scheme-theoretic fiber of $V$ over $y'$, and this fiber is reduced iff $I(y')$ is radical.

Comment: Thank you. Do you happen to know of a source? The source given in the link you sent me was broken unfortunately.

Comment: In EGA IV.9.7.7 it is proved that the property of a fiber being geometrically reduced is locally constructible on the base. It follows that if the fiber over the generic point has this property, then it holds on an open subset.

Comment: What I am still confused about is the description of the generic fiber as $\mathrm{Spec} K(A)\otimes_A B$, where in our case $A=\mathbb C[y]/I(\pi(V))$ and $B=\mathbb C[x,y]/I(V)$. This fiber does not depend on $y'\in \pi(V)$. In contrast, Hartshorne's definition of fiber of a point is $\mathrm{Spec} \mathbb C[y]/I(y=y') \otimes_A B$ (Chapter 2, Section 3.) I'm guessing that you are saying that the latter spectrum is isomorphic to $\mathbb C[x]/I(y')$, which is the ideal we want to be radical. How do I see that the two descriptions are the same?

Comment: By generic fiber I mean the fiber over generic point of the base scheme (the closure of this point is the whole scheme). And the fiber over a point $y'$ belonging to an open subset of the base is usually called the general fiber.

Comment: Let me clarify: In the link you sent me, they refer to the fiber of the generic point, but in my context I want the fiber of a general point. And your claim is that by the EGA result, the fact that it holds for the generic point, means that it holds for a general point? Further, the scheme-theoretic fiber of $V$ over the general point $y'$ (as defined by Harthshorne) is the spectrum of $\mathbb C[x]/I(y')$? Thank you in advance.

Comment: All is correct. If a locally constructible subset of an affine space (or any irreducible Noetherian scheme) contains the generic point, then it contains all points from some open subset.

Comment: In fact it holds for any irreducible scheme.

Comment: Finally, I should understand why the spectrum of $\mathbb C[x]/I(y')$ is isomorphic to the scheme-theoretic fiber of $V$ over $y'$. I don't immediately see this using Hartshorne's definition. Do you know of a source for this, or can you explain it? Thanks.

Comment: See Vakil's notes Foundations of Algebraic Geometry, Exercise 10.2.B. And note that $\mathbb C[x, y]/(I, y-y') \cong \mathbb C[x]/I(y')$. The notes are available at http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!